# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT with worker_threads & express on Node Js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, node-worker-threads

I am trying to manipulate workers from API requests.

Starting worker through "/start" and waiting for commands (messages)

After that - send command to worker with "/test".

First request to "/test" works well and I got correct response, but on second - I got "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT".

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");

const workers = []

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/start', function (req, res) {

    const threadName = req.query.threadName
    const workerData = { threadName: threadName }

    const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", { workerData });

    worker.postMessage({ status: 'start' });
    workers.push({ threadName: threadName, worker: worker })

    worker.on("message", async (message) => {

        if(message.status === "ready") {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message : "thread is ready",
                threadName : threadName
            })
        }

    });

})

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {

    const threadName = req.query.threadName
    const worker = workers.filter((worker) => worker.threadName === threadName)[0].worker

    worker.postMessage({ status: 'test' });

    worker.on("message", (message) => {

        if(message.status === "test_success") {
            return res.status(200).json({
                msg : "test success",
                threadName : threadName
            })
        }

    });

})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

worker.js

```
const { parentPort, threadId } = require("worker_threads");
      
parentPort.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.status === "start") {
    parentPort.postMessage({ status: 'ready', threadId: threadId });
  } else if(message.status === "test") {
    parentPort.postMessage({ status: 'test_success', threadId: threadId });
  }

});
```